# What are the disadvantages of linked lists?

Tags: list, data-structures

what are the disadvantages of linked list? Isn't this little time consuming ? 
if yes,then how can we reduce the execution time/reaction time for getting the desired output?

Comment: Advantages and disadvantages are relative, and drastically depend on the situation.

Comment: i think the main one is: `no random access`

Comment: Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) first.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , yeah,that's the fact... depends on the situations

Comment: i think extra storage needed for references, which often makes them impractical for lists of small data items such as characters or boolean values. It can also be slow, and with a naïve allocator, wasteful, to allocate memory separately for each new element, a problem generally solved using memory pools... :/

Comment: I was reading a blog by a 20 year veteran programmer who noted that he learnt linked lists when he started out but has yet to use them. So perhaps the disadvantage is that they never get used! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each data structure is meant for given set of purposes and is good in solving certain types of problems and bad in others. For instance a disadvantage of linked list is that you can not efficiently get the minimum element in it. But linked list *is not meant* to be used for that. There are numerous implementations of linked list and asking if **it** is little time consuming is pointless without specifying **which implementation** and for which **operation**.

Still no matter the question the answer to `if yes,then how can we reduce the execution time/reaction time for getting the desired output?` is: either use another implementation of linked list or use another data structure. No structure is better in being linked list than... linked list.